# Elm, JSON decoder: How to decode an empty string?

Tags: elm

What's the best way to handle an empty (no string at all) response?

Although the response code is 200, Elm returns an error because an empty response is not a valid JSON.

Here is my current code:

```
decodeAlwaysTrue : Json.Decode.Decoder Bool
decodeAlwaysTrue =
  Json.Decode.succeed True

Http.send Http.defaultSettings httpConfig
  |> Http.fromJson decodeAlwaysTrue
  |> Task.perform FetchFail DeleteUserSuccess
```

EDIT1:

This a POST action so I can't use [getString](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-http/3.0.1/Http#getString).

Comment: I like your current approach. `succeed` says: "no matter what you get here, it's fine."

Comment: @SørenDebois Not exactly. It will succeed if the response code is 2xx and the response is a valid JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`getString`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-http/3.0.1/Http#getString) function from the `Http` module. That will give you back whatever string is returned from the HTTP request without attempting to convert is to a Json value.

If you instead need to use `Http.send` then you could do something like this:

```elm
Http.send Http.defaultSettings httpConfig
  |> Task.perform FetchFail (always DeleteUserSuccess)
```

This assumes that `DeleteUserSuccess` is changed to be defined with no type parameter:

```elm
type Msg =
  ...
  DeleteUserSuccess
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are never getting back a Json response so you'll probably be better using [Http.getString](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-http/3.0.1/Http#getString)

```
type Result = FetchFail Error
            | DeleteUserSuccess

Http.getString address
  |> Task.perform FetchFail (\s -> DeleteUserSuccess)
```

Since the successful get doesn't contain any information you can just ignore it and return `DeleteUserSuccess` regardless of the content of the string.

Comment: See EDIT1 in my initial question